# Where is Transfer attribute in 3.4?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Where is *Transfer attribute* node in 3.4? I don't find it in the list of nodes:

[image]

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The *Transfer Attribute* has been replaced by the set of nodes.

*Transfer Attribute* in *Nearest Surface Point* mode is now *Sample Nearest Surface*:

[image]

*Transfer Attribute* in *Index* mode is now *Sample Index* and is used in combination with the *Index* node:

[image]

*Transfer Attribute* in *Nearest* mode is now *Sample Nearest* and is used in combination with the *Sample Index* node:

[image]

By the way, you can check the updates related to *Geometry Nodes* here:
[Can't find the node! Which node is available in which Blender version?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273541/)

...or the more detailed version with corresponding links to the documentation of the individual nodes:
https://geometry-nodes-overview.docs.quellenform.at/
<sub>(This list is constantly updating)</sub>

Comment: Great contribution! I have also linked this in the [Geometry Nodes Overview](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/273542/145249)

Comment: acting in advance

Comment: I haven't used 3.4 geonodes yet, but until now you didn't have to connect index to index, as that was done implicitly (just like you don't have to connect UV map to an image texture in shader). You already take advantage of that by not connecting anything to the "Sample Position" (the position node is implied, probably)

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady maybe it may change in the future, but currently *Sample index* has default value instead of index field in *Transfer attribute*

Comment: I have some issues working with this feature, I saw lot of tutorials which shows how to transform from one object into another using transfer attribute and I am not able to reproduce with the new kind of nodes. I just want to morph a cube into a cylinder. I only achieved so far a transformation from cube to a line.

Comment: I don´t understand why the transfer attribute node has been replaced by this seemingly more complicated set up of nodes. Can someone enlighten me? Thanks!

Comment: @Victor nobody knows