# Arc Between Edge Endpoints Using Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Would it be possible to draw a circle arc between edge endpoints of a mesh as shown below?

The mesh consists of nothing but the two edges.

[image: Arc At Edge Endpoints]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a setup that should work for your specific mesh:

[image]

[image]

*What I'm doing:*

- First, I delete the vertices that has more than one neighboring edges, which in your setup means only the vertex at the center gets deleted since it has two neighboring edges.
- Now that I'm left with two vertices at the endpoints of the edges, I can be certain of their indices ($0$ and $1$). I *Sample* them at those *Index* numbers to get their *Position*s, and use those positions as the *Start* and *End* points for the *Arc* curve primitive in *Points* mode.
- I'm also using an Empty object to control the *Middle* point. You can use just numbers, but a visual aid like that might be more convenient.

Comment: I had worked out a solution but this is much cleaner and simpler. I am trying this one now. Thank you! Could you tell me where exactly is the Sample Index node? I didn't find it through search. I am using Blender version 3.3.1.

Comment: I'm using 3.4. Sample Index is one of several new nodes that replaced the Transfer Attribute node: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/276088/71578 You can either use Transfer Attribute, or switch to 3.4 Beta if you want to be more up to date.