# Geometry Nodes: Changing instances rotation to 'normal' after simulation?

Tags: geometry-nodes, simulation-nodes

I have this Circuit Board generator which uses the simulation nodes of [Blender 3.5 Alpha (simulation node build)](https://builder.blender.org/download/experimental/)

How can I rotate the black-and-yellow-dots to point along the surface like so?

Press Space to play the simulation and keep it updating the results, sometimes needed.

[image]

I've tried all kinds of capturing normals and other ways and no dice :(

.blend file:
https://files.manujarvinen.com/circuit_board_test4_problem.blend

(Note: Blend-Exchange refused to host the file, maybe something to do with the simulation nodes.)

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a `Sample Nearest Surface` node (used to be part of [the now-defunct *Transfer Attribute* node](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/276087/where-is-transfer-attribute-in-3-4)) to transfer the face orientations from the original geometry to feed an `Align Euler to Vector`:

[image]

Comment: Wowww, thank you both who provided similar answers. I had no idea that 'there' were the functions of the now-missing transfer-node. Great, great, great!

Answer (score 4):

try this:

[image]

result:

[image]

You need the sample nearest+index for this.

Comment: Thank you! I shall mark the other almost the same time appeared answer as final since it seems to be a bit tidier = more useful to the community. Thank you so much anyway :)

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 2):

I managed to achieve satisfactory (but not perfect) result:

[image]

Curve-to-Points-node was used to get the rotation for the instances and then I just rotated the cylinder 90 degrees with the transform-node.

[image]