# Replacement for the transfer attribute in Blender 3.4

Tags: geometry-nodes, animation-nodes, procedural

I'm fairly new to geo-nodes in blender and really want to reproduce an effect I've seen in a tutorial. At the timestamp in this video Cleverpoly uses a "transfer attribute" to bring the displaced mesh back to its original state, but blender has removed this feature. Does anyone know a work around?
https://youtu.be/C64H1eEga-k?t=400

I have tried these options but clearly don't understand what there doing.
[Where is Transfer attribute in 3.4?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/276087/where-is-transfer-attribute-in-3-4)

[image]

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Right now if someone wants to understand what you are asking, they have to watch the tutorial. I think you should form a question that is clear on its own. What do you want to do with the nodes? Why not post a screenshot with all the nodes working with Transfer Attribute node that you want to replace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're following a tutorial, use the Blender version used in the tutorial. You can see in the video, **Blender 3.4 Alpha** was used. The problem here is, alpha versions are prototypes, their functionality is subject to change, it's a work-in-progress. So unlike Beta versions which are unstable, Alpha versions are more unstable and their feature (like available nodes) may change. This is why I think it's a poor idea to create educational content based on alpha versions (and this is why I think I never used such versions here on BSE).

I think as a general rule, when you see a material made in version **X.Y Alpha**, you should try versions **X.(Y-1) Stable** and **X.Y Stable**. It doesn't guarantee success, because some future are introduced in the development cycle only to be removed at the end of the alpha cycle (like recently Simulation Nodes or viewport Compositor). They may be available in forks, or in newest alphas as experimental features etc. - it requires some research to find them.

In your case, the *"Transfer Attribute"* node was available in versions 3.0-3.3 (or 2.93α-3.4α I think). You can use a tool like [Blender Launcher](https://dotbow.github.io/Blender-Launcher/) to download B3.3 and try to create the node tree from the tutorial in that version. Once you're done, you can save your project and reopen it in a newer version, Blender will then convert the old way to the new way by replacing the nodes. At least in this case, of "TA" nodes, Blender does a good job of converting to a new version.

Here's an example, a 3.0 project opened in Blender 3.0:

[image]

And the same file opened in Blender 3.5:

[image]

You can see the positioning is not as pretty, especially in the case where one node was replaced by two nodes:

[image] → [image]

So "Transfer Attribute" by index simply became "Sample Index", whereas "TA" in "nearest" mode became two nodes: first find the index of the nearest element using "Sample Nearest", and then use that obtained index in the "Sample Index" node.