# An array of random elements of different sizes

Tags: geometry-nodes

My task is to make a mosaic like in the picture.

[image: Mosaic]

But to assemble it manually for an entire room, and even in several rows, is quite long and difficult. Therefore, I have a question is there a way to procedurally generate a mosaic from a collection of elements, taking into account the fact that the sizes of the elements differ?

**[Update 1]** So I was shown a similar scheme [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/250422/how-to-position-random-instances-one-after-another-with-instance-on-points-based). And I made such a node tree:

[image: Node Tree]

However, I still can't get the desired result. I get either an array with empty spaces if I use Max Bounding Box:

[image]

Or getting a hodgepodge of objects if I use Min Bounding Box:
[image]

**[Update 2]**
The solution suggested by Robin Betts is what I was looking for, thank you. You can find it [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/250422/how-to-position-random-instances-one-after-another-with-instance-on-points-based)

Comment: I have added another method to the dupe, getting rid of the manual steps in the accepted answer

Comment: The instance index seems doesn't correlate with selected bound box. You have 5 boxes, but you take a module from 11