# Accumulate field with a collection

Tags: geometry-nodes

Does anyone know how to make this works with a collection.
I tries implementing a bounding box node and accumulate the max z dimensions but i cant make it work. This screenshot came from Chris in reaction to another question

[image]

[image]

Edit:

This was my solution but it doesnt work.
[image]

Comment: There's some other thread here with a [few answers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/250422/how-to-position-random-instances-one-after-another-with-instance-on-points-based/), it's not something that works out of the box yet, looks like 'Bounding Box' doesn't do fields or something... [here's a blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/49zcjzen8l0egrn/acumulado.blend?dl=1) with my hackish solution, but there's something alike in there too.

Comment: @alambre: why do you think it is hackish? i would write that as an answer! Great job!

Comment: thanks..! maybe they all are? bounding box should work in this cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@alambre had the answer here. Thanks this works.

Edit:
linking to Robin Betts solution ;)

[image]

[image]

Comment: nice but don't credit me, that is the 'Capturing Dimensions on Instances' setup that Robin Betts uploaded in that thread... I did almost the same thing though