# Geometry Nodes: Objects with different dimensions follow curve and snap next to each other

Tags: geometry-nodes

What I am looking for is a way to snap multiple objects from a collection next to each other while they follow a curve.

I found this [great example from Frank Firsching](https://gitlab.com/subdivided_xyz/nodes_xyz/-/blob/main/geoNodes/deformObjectsToCurve.blend). However, I can't seem to get the objects next to each other and not on top of each other.

Also I can't find a way to disable the strange rotation the objects get. I want them to always stand up straight.

This is what the example is doing:
[image]

This is what I am trying to create:
[image]

Does anybody know how to realign the objects or does anybody have a simpler solution for my question?

Thanks!

ps. if you want to see the node setup, please look at the .blend file as it is pretty complex.
[image]

Comment: This _may_ be a duplicate of the question answered [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/251488/35559) ... what do you think?

Comment: Hi Robin, yes I think so. I will look into that post for the solution. Thanks.

Comment: I think there is already an answer of this somewhere on here. you want to instance if you don't want working.

Comment: Erin has a tutorial https://youtu.be/Ms6CX8Gsd5A