Offsetting instances from a bounding box vector
I am trying to get objects instancing 3 units apart from each other on a grid. I know how to get the points to be 3 units apart, but I would then love to have the objects be distanced 3 units apart in a dynamic way. but when I go ahead and have bounding boxes on the collection it seems like geometry nodes doesnt work well with instances and becomes static?
I come from a procedural cad background, so in other tools I am able to store an attribute to a class/id. I.e store a named attribute (3 units offset) to each of these objects and can then be carried on to each index accordingly. I am struggling to also find a solution for that..
Thank you!




What is a dynamic way?
Do you mean 3 meters of gap between each object? In a grid, that would mean an irregular grid, similar to the first image, is that the objective?

Similar to the first screenshot, yes. The end goal is that I want to increase and decrease the size of this grid that spaces out the points in 3’ gap+the edge of the object. So if there’s a way I can assign that variable of distance from center of object to edge for each type of bounding box.

In your case all objects are very similar in size. Does this correctly portray your case? Consider how much more complicated the algorithm will have to be if there will be column/row intertwining, because the objects are of drastically different size (so that columns/rows no longer line up)

Is this what you mean? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/250422/how-to-position-random-instances-one-after-another-with-instance-on-points-based
